# SignalR Synchronous calls blocking limits

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr.client

When working with SignalR making synchronous calls from a client, based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#asyncmethods):

> When a Hub method executes synchronously and the transport is
>   WebSocket, subsequent invocations of methods on the Hub from the same
>   client are blocked until the Hub method completes.

That could provoke a queue of requests in the client waiting until the Hub methods completes. So we could have an scenario with three requests, as following:
[image]

In this scenario the 3rd request has been waiting for 1 minute.

My questions are:

- Is there any limit in the amount of time a request will be waiting?
- Is there any limit in the amount of requests waiting in the queue?

Comment: There is no limit. However you can Invoke the method and not await the task but keep for later to retrieve the result once the call actually completes. There is no explicit limit on the queue. SignalR is using async features of C#/CLR and this is CLR that manages all these tasks.